# filter javascript object with key value

Tags: javascript

I am filtering a javascript object..

```
[{
   title: 'example1',
   categorySlug: 'cat-1',
   categoryName: 'hello1'
}
{
   title: 'example2',
   categorySlug: 'cat-2',
   categoryName: 'hello2'
}
{
   title: 'example3',
   categorySlug: 'cat-1',
   categoryName: 'hello1'
}]
```

I need the object as below

```
[{
    categorySlug: "cat1",
    categoryName: "hello1",
    data: [{
        {
            title: "example1",
            categorySlug: 'cat-1',
            categoryName: 'hello1'
        },
        {
            title: "example1",
            categorySlug: 'cat-1',
            categoryName: 'hello1'
        }
    }]
},
 {
    categorySlug: "cat2",
    categoryName: "hello2",
    data: [{
        {
            title: "example2",
            categorySlug: 'cat-2',
            categoryName: 'hello2'
        }
    }]
}
]
```

I need to filter the object.  I have tried with many way but I have faield to filter the object.

#I have added one more category And I nedd to filter like that.

Comment: Is `categorySlug` and `categoryName` always the same in pairs? (i.e. `cat-2` always together with `hello2` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [array map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const array = [{
   title: 'example1',
   categorySlug: 'cat-1',
   categoryName: 'hello1'
}
{
   title: 'example2',
   categorySlug: 'cat-2',
   categoryName: 'hello2'
}]

// map over the objects within array
const newArray = array.map((category) => ({ categorySlug: category.categorySlug,
   categoryName: category.categoryName, data: [category] }))
```

Bare in mind the map method does not mutate the original array. Meaning 'array' will stay the same but 'newArray' will contain your new array with your new data structure

Comment: categorySlug is being duplicate when more than one category slug ..can you please help

Comment: please see the question again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objectArray = [{
   title: 'example1',
   categorySlug: 'cat-1',
   categoryName: 'hello1'
},
{
   title: 'example2',
   categorySlug: 'cat-2',
   categoryName: 'hello2'
}]

var newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
   const items = objectArray[i];
    newArray.push({
      categorySlug: items.categorySlug,
      categoryName: items.categoryName,
       data: [items]
    })

}

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: it is not filtering when more that one categorySlug

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is more like grouping and not filtering. I think the below script will satisfy you.

```js
const array = [{
    title: 'example1',
    categorySlug: 'cat-1',
    categoryName: 'hello1'
},
{
    title: 'example2',
    categorySlug: 'cat-2',
    categoryName: 'hello2'
},
{
    title: 'example3',
    categorySlug: 'cat-1',
    categoryName: 'hello1'
}]

const result = array
    .filter((value, index, self) => index === self.findIndex((item) => item.categoryName === value.categoryName))
    .map(({ title, ...category }) => {
        return { ...category, data: array.filter((item) => item.categoryName === category.categoryName) };
    });

console.log(result)
```